# Get all Settings.System keys

Tags: android

I am playing around with the [`Settings.System`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.System.html) class of Android and used an app to get all my phone's settings. That app show way more settings that can be found in the official Android docs and when I try to get them with the `getString` method, I can read them.

What I cannot find though, is a way to get all setting-keys. How could I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use reflection to find all of the static data members defined on `Settings.System`, filter the results to only be the ones defined as `String` values, and try them as keys, I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

`adb shell settings list system`